# mvc3 how to pass selected item of a dropdown list from one view to another viaction link

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a drop down list 
in Razor View

```
@Html.DropDownList("ddlAccount", items)
```

this drop down list is binded with items.

I want to pass this selected list item to 'Create' Method of "TaskManagement" Controller on click of action link.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Create New Task", "Create", "KTTaskManagement")
```

Answer (score 1):

The semantically correct way to handle this case is to use a form instead of an anchor:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "KTTaskManagement"))
{
    @Html.DropDownList("ddlAccount", items)
    <button type="submit">Create New Task</button>
}
```

This way the selected value of the dropdown will be automatically sent to the controller action:

```
public ActionResult Create(string ddlAccount)
{
    // the action argument will contain the selected value
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

And while your at it please use the typed equivalence

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedItemId, new
 SelectList(Model.Items, "ItemId", "ItemName", Model.SelectedItemId))
```

Comment: DataBinding: 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem' does not contain a property with the name 'Id'